# Mac Disk Utility

Tags: macos, disk

In disk utility, I accidentally clicked the up arrow icon next to the volume under external, and the volume disappear. What does the icon does and how can I revert it?
[image: disk utility]

Comment: This is not a programming question and should be removed. Better to ask it at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That is the eject icon, and you may revert the ejection by remounting that external disk, usually by unplugging the unit and plugging it in again.

Comment: The disk is LibreOffice, an application I downloaded. How can I remount it?

Comment: The picture is not from my computer. May be the libre office is not under external, but disk image.

Comment: @HKIT Find the disk image you downloaded, and re-open it. BTW, running apps from a disk image is generally a bad idea; you should copy the app it to your Applications folder and run it from there.

Comment: What's the disadvantage of running apps from a disk image?

Comment: Maybe you should read the section "Answer well-asked questions" in the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page in the Help Center.

Comment: @HKIT Mostly, running apps from a disk image has potential problems that running them from /Applications doesn't. For instance, if you update the app in /Applications, everything uses the new version. But if it's in a disk image, you may have aliases, shortcuts, etc that still refer to the old version and try to open it. You also have to be careful not to delete a disk image that's still in use, quarantine may not get cleanly cleared, etc...